# Connecting Local Neo4j Graph to Databricks Cluster

Tags: neo4j, databricks

I've created a Neo4j Local Graph DB containing some data that I need to use on a Databricks Notebook to do some graph analysis. I've seen that there's the Neo4j Spark Connector available and I was wondering if it were possible to access my local db using it, I don't have any hosting service available for my database and haven't managed to find one that offers a free trial and it's fairly easy to setup with Neo4j.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm fairly with both Neo4j and Databricks so I hope my question is fairly explained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're running Neo4j on localhost with the default ports, you onl have to configure your password in `spark.neo4j.bolt.password=<password>`.

Otherwise set the `spark.neo4j.bolt.url` in your `SparkConf` pointing e.g. to `bolt://host:port`.

You can provide user and password as part of the URL `bolt://neo4j:<password>@localhost` or individually in `spark.neo4j.bolt.user` and `spark.neo4j.bolt.password`.

For more details, refer "[Neo4j Connector to Apache Spark"](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-spark-connector).

Hope this helps.